# Is it possible to determine whether a particular notification channel is blocked?

Tags: android-notifications

On Android Oreo (8.0) and later devices, a user can turn off notifications for an app on three different levels:

1. At the app level
2. At the notification channel group level
3. At the notification channel level

This is demonstrated in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of app's notification settings]

I know I can detect whether notifications are turned off at levels 1 and 2 by means of the [NotificationsManager.areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#areNotificationsEnabled()) and [NotificationChannelGroup.isBlocked()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannelGroup#isBlocked()) methods respectively.

I cannot see such an "isEnabled" or "isBlocked" method in the [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) class. Is it possible to determine whether notifications are blocked for a particular notification channel? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether notifications are disabled for a particular channel by checking whether [NotificationChannel.getImportance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#getImportance()) equals [NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_NONE).